# IN NativeScript not able to connect to Facebook

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, nativescript

I have installed pod

> pod 'FacebookSDK',
>
> pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
>
> pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

This is installed properly.via pod file.

code inside my app.js

> 

```
const application = require("tns-core-modules/application"); 
if(application.ios){
var AppDelegate = NSObject.extend({
       applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions :function (application, launchOptions) {
         var gglDelegate = false;
         try {
            var errorRef = new interop.Reference();
            GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(errorRef);
            var signIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance();
            gglDelegate = true;
        } catch (error) {  console.log(error);    }
        var fcbDelegate = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions(application, launchOptions); // facebook login delegate
                                  return gglDelegate || fcbDelegate;
      },
     applicationOpenURLSourceApplicationAnnotation : function (application, url, sourceApplication, annotation) {
         var fcbDelegate = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().applicationOpenURLSourceApplicationAnnotation(application, url, sourceApplication, annotation); // facebook login delegate
          var gglDelegate = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURLSourceApplicationAnnotation(url, sourceApplication, annotation); // google login delegate
           return fcbDelegate || gglDelegate;
        }                         
},{
     name: "AppDelegate",
     ObjCProtocols:[UIApplicationDelegate , UIResponder ]  
});  
}
application.run({ moduleName: "app-root" });
```

i am trying to use demo https://github.com/mkloubert/nativescript-social-login/tree/master/demo , but in my project. But i am not using Any nativescript framework. My project is based on simple plain javascript demo.typescript or angular does not work on my project.

but still i am having this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your syntax was not correct. Extend from `UIResponder` and use `protocols` instead of `ObjCProtocols` when passing it as second argument to extend function.

```
var AppDelegate = UIResponder.extend({
    ....
    ....
}, {
    name: "AppDelegate",
    protocols: [UIApplicationDelegate]
});
```

And set the delegate before running the app,

```
application.ios.delegate = AppDelegate
```

Comment: I have tried that but things not working new error will be FBSDKapplicationDelegate not defined

Comment: You will hit that error only when you POD is not installed. Are you using the plugin, if yes I'm wondering why you mentioned that you installed the pods via pod file as it will be part of plugin itself.

Comment: what should i do to fix that

Comment: Are you using the plug-in or installing pod yourself?

Comment: i am first installing pod file paste "pod FBSDKcorekit .... "   then pod update , 
as when i install nativescript-social-login . it does not install these plugin automatically.

Comment: i also have tries solution you have given me but its not working 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756585/i-am-getting-this-error-cant-find-variable-fbsdkapplicationdelegate

Comment: Installing the plug-in will include pod, just do a clean build it should install pods automatically.

Comment: The solution given was for extending app delegate with JS,  not being able to install pod is a different issue and a clean build always install pods from plug-ins properly.

Comment: i have removed from pod , reinstalled plugin again but it seems it cant find FBSDKApplicationDelegate.
tns plugin add nativesctipt-social-login . also i have tried reinstalling using npm -i nativescript-social-login --save .